# Eclipse Oxygen Java 8 foreach lambda expression code completion broken

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda, java-8, eclipse-oxygen

I just switched recently to Oxygen and fighting with code completion issues inside foreach blocks.

```
 final XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
  sheet.forEach(row -> {
    row.forEach(cell -> {
      if (row.getRowNum() == 1) { // There is getRownum method on row

      } 
    });
  });
```

There is no code completion for **row** or **cell** objects except the class method. Even there is **getRownNum()** method on the row object the content assist doesn't shows it. Is there any quick fix for this issue or just rolling back to the previous Eclipse version?